# Enabling Button after multi button Select

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a windows form C# application in which I need to enable a button4 button if and only if all three buttons (button1, button2, button3) are clicked. I am struggling to implement this. Help me out with some ideas and samples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can for example create a boolean field for each of the buttons and set that to true when a button is clicked.

Comment: LOL. How to click three buttons at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossiple to have 3 buttons clicked, as you cannot press with your mouse on all three at the same time.

If you mean that they have been clicked, look at the following code.

```
int index = 0;

button1.Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    index = index + 1;
    button1.enabled = false;
}
button2.Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    index = index + 1;
    button2.enabled = false;
}
button3.Click(object sender, eventarfs e)
{
    index = index + 1;
    button3.enabled = false;
}
//And now the button to see if all buttons have been clicked:
button4.Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    if (index == 3)
    {
        Messagebox.Show("All buttons have been clicked.")
    }
    else
    {
        Messagebox.Show("Not all buttons have been clicked")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a CheckBox. You can make CheckBoxes look like button by using this kind of code:

```
var checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
var checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
var checkBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
var checkBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox(); 
checkBox1.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button; 
checkBox2.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button; 
checkBox3.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button; 
checkBox4.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
```

And then to do what you are trying to do:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked)
    checkBox4.Enabled = true;
else
    checkBox4.Enabled = false;
```

Or you can one line it:

```
checkBox4.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, bool> buttonClicked = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
private void button123_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonName = (sender as Button).Name;
    if (!buttonClicked.ContainsKey(buttonName))
    {
        buttonClicked.Add(buttonName, true);
    }
    if (buttonClicked.Count == 3) button4.Enabled = true;
}
```

Add this as the `OnClick` event of the first 3 buttons and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add this list to your class' root:

```
List<Button> pressedButtons = new List<Button>();
```

Then add this method to your 1, 2, and 3 buttons' "Click"-event (use this same method for all 3):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Add the clicked button to the list
   pressedButtons.Add((Button)sender);

   // If all 3 are on the list, enable button4
   if (pressedButtons.Count == 3) { button4.Enabled = true; }
}
```

You should check out the "*CheckBox*"-element, as it can be used with Button-appeareance (by setting the "*Appeareance*"-property. This way you can have a button with toggle on-off ability.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the buttons in the List or array and  use Tag property of the Button. There is a code of click event handler for all 3 buttons:

```
//Create a list
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(){button1,button2,button3};
```

Click Event handler for 3 buttons

```
private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Update Tag value
        if (((Button)sender).Tag == null || (bool)((Button)sender).Tag == false)
            ((Button)sender).Tag = true;

        //Check state of all buttons
        foreach (Button btn in buttons)
        {   
            //One of the buttons wasn't clicked
            if ((bool)btn.Tag == false)if (((Button)sender).Tag == null || (bool)((Button)sender).Tag == false)
                return;
        }
        //All buttons were clicked
        button4.Enabled = true;
    }
```